# Why is Highchart loaded twice in my rails app ? (Uncaught Highcharts error #16)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I can't make working the basic example of Highcharts.

I got these errors :

`Uncaught Highcharts error #16` in app/assets/javascripts/application.js
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in app/assets/javascripts/graphique_repartition_budgetaire

Highcharts says that the error 16 is because :

> This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded
>   in the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep
>   in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of
>   Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and
>   StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js
>   file.

But I can't figure out how can Highcharts could be loaded twice in the same page.

**I'm using Rails 3.2.21**

I put this into my Gemfile :

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
```

I put this into my app/assets/javascripts/application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require highcharts
```

I put this into my app/views/layouts/application.html.haml :

```
%html
  %head
    %title My title blablabla
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', :media => 'screen'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', :media => 'print, projection'
    /[if IE]
      = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', :media => 'screen, projection'
    = csrf_meta_tags
...
```

This is the code I have in my view (HAML-like) :

```
.groupe-champs-encadres
  #graphique-repartition-budgetaire
```

This is the what I put into my stylesheet (SASS-like) :

```
#graphique-repartition-budgetaire
  width: 100%
  height: 400px
```

This is the code (frome Highcharts example) that I put into my app/assets/javascripts/graphique_repartition_budgetaire.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#graphique-repartition-budgetaire').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

====== EDIT 1 ======

I notice that this error also happen on other pages that don't use any ID : #graphique-repartition-budgetaire".
In other words, the error also happen on pages that don't use the javascript Highcharts.

So this excludes a mistake on the view itself where the javascript chart example function is called (though the Highcharts.js is of course called on every page).
The problem should lie somewhere else.

====== EDIT 2 ======

I made this simple [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273292/what-do-i-need-to-do-check-to-see-if-jquery-is-installed-in-my-rails-3-project) to check if jquery is working properly.
And it fails. It doesn't display the "TEST" on my page.
So there must be a problem with jquery and Rails 3.2.
I saw on stackoverflow that some people also got problem making jquery working. But I did't find any working solution for now.

====== EDIT 3 ======

There is something wrong with the recommanded [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273292/what-do-i-need-to-do-check-to-see-if-jquery-is-installed-in-my-rails-3-project). It was not working until I save the script into a file app/assets/javascript/display_my_div.js, and changed it to :

```
$(function() {
  $('#mydiv').show();
});
```

So JQuery is working like a charm. The problem is definitively linked with Highcharts library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found that there is a bug in rails when you do a `rake assets:precompile` that would lead to include twice the JS code from app/assets and public/assets.

This bug is referenced [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10091) since april 2013, but the rails community don't seem to be willing to correct it.

As workaround I just :

1. run `rake assets:clean`
2. add the line `//= require highcharts` to
   **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**
3. run `rake assets:precompile`
4. **delete** the line `//= require highcharts` from  **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

So Highchart library is precompiled in assets pipeline from the public/assets.

Its a bit weird, but it works... in development...

I still have to test it in production to confirm that it continues to work.

=== EDIT 1 ===

In fact, it simpler than that :
In developpement mode, Rails auto-compile your JS files, but if they were already precompiled with the `rake:assets precompile` command and compressed into a file (I dont remember where yet) ; then rails would use both occurence of your JS code.
This would of course not happen in production mode as there is (usually) no auto-compile mode activated (for performance consideration).