# Where should I put my page related javascript code in Rails 3.2 using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using JQuery and Highcharts.

Here it is my app/assets/javascripts/ folder's content :

```
application.js
graphique_repartition_budgetaire.js.erb
proj_charge.js.erb
```

Here it is my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file ... bla bla bla ...
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require highcharts
```

Here it is my app/assets/javascripts/graphique_repartition_budgetaire.js.erb file

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: "'"
        }
    });
    $('#graphique-repartition-budgetaire').highcharts({
      // my graphic code is here....
    });
});
```

Until there it's working fine.
The problems rise when I try to code other javascript/JQuery for an other specific page. I put this new code into a file app/assets/javascripts/proj_charge.js.erb :

```
$(function () {
  alert('JQuery is ready !');
});
```

This file doesn't execute and doesn't seem to be loaded either.
Why ?
Should I put all my jQuery code into the same file ?
I'm a beginnner with Javascript and JQuery so I dont know if maybe it is forbidden to declare twice the same `$(function () {});`

What am I doign wrong ?

**=== EDIT ===**

I included the code at the end of my applicationjs file :

```
// This is a manifest file ... bla bla bla ...
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require highchart
$(function () {
  alert('JQuery is ready !');
});
```

Then I stopped my web server, compiled assets, and restarted web server :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
rake assets:precompile
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Nothing happen and the code still doesn't appear in the source page of firebug.

Comment: Declaring $(function () {}); twice will not break your code, because it's just checking if the DOM is ready so there is no need to do more than once. The fact it's not loading is a separate issue related to Rails I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this.

The issue was coming from my development environnement using Highcharts and the asset pipeline.
In fact my javascript graph call for Highchart was existing in app/assets/javascripts/graphique_repartition_budgetaire.js.erb, and was also existing into my pre-compiled asset (built by my `rake assets:precompile` command).

This was causing an [error in Highchart library](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16)

This error prevented my javascript code in proj_charge.js.erb to be executed.
That is why it was not showing the alert message.

I explained the solution to solve this asset precompile issue in developement mode in the following post :
[Why is Highchart loaded twice in my rails app ? (Uncaught Highcharts error #16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389863/why-is-highchart-loaded-twice-in-my-rails-app-uncaught-highcharts-error-16)